# Searching within text fields in CloudKit

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit

How are people searching *within* a string (a substring) field using CloudKit?

For making predicates for use with CloudKit, from what I gather, you can only can only do `BEGINSWITH` and `TOKENMATCHES` to search search a single text field's (prefix) or all fields (exact match) respectively. `CONTAINS` only works on collections despite [these examples](http://nshipster.com/cloudkit/). I can't determine a way to find, for example, *roses* in the following string "Red roses are pretty"

I was thinking of making a **tokenized version** of certain string fields; for example the following fields on a hypothetical record:

- `description: 'Red roses are pretty'`
- `descriptionTokenized: ['Red', 'roses', 'are', 'pretty']`

testing this out makes `CONTAINS` somewhat useful when searching for distinct, space separated substrings but still not as good as SQL `LIKE` would be.